# making logic for quiz app using titanium

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, titanium, logic

Hi I am making a quiz app using titanium.The data has been received well in the arrays.Now i am trapped how to update the label each time a next button is pressed because if i make the labels in event listener.They are no more available to me for the first run.Here is my code:

```
    var btnnext = Titanium.UI.createButton({
title : 'Next',
bottom : '20%',
width : '50%',
height : '10%'
 });
btnnext.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
quiz_counter++;
});
QuizWin.add(btnnext);
var labquiz = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
text : quizes[quiz_counter],
top : '20%',
left : '10%',
color : 'black'
 });
QuizWin.add(labquiz);

var laboption1 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
text : option1[quiz_counter],
top : '30%',
left : '10%',
color : 'black'
 });

QuizWin.add(laboption1);

var laboption2 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
text : option2[quiz_counter],
top : '40%',
left : '10%',
color : 'black'
 });
 QuizWin.add(laboption2);

var laboption3 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
text : option3[quiz_counter],
top : '50%',
left : '10%',
color : 'black'
});
QuizWin.add(laboption3);

var laboption4 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
text : option4[quiz_counter],
top : '60%',
left : '10%',
color : 'black'

 });

 QuizWin.add(laboption4);
```

Comment: What is this titanium in iphone

Comment: yeah iPhone coding written in java script with titanium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically your question is, "How do I store a variable outside of a JavaScript function [scope], so I can access it later?" This is such a fundamental thing to programming and JavaScript that I'm not sure I should answer this. It's why you've gotten a couple down votes. The below snippet demonstrates scopes.

```
var outside = false;

function f() {
    var inside = true;
    outside = true;
}

f();

alert(outside + ', ' + inside);
```